# grep based on blacklist -- without procedural code?

Tags: linux, grep, blacklist

It's a well-known task, simple to describe:

Given a text file foo.txt, and a blacklist file of exclusion strings, one per line, produce foo_filtered.txt that has only the lines of foo.txt that do not contain any exclusion string.

A common application is filtering compiler warnings from a build log, but to ignore warnings on files that are not yours. The file foo.txt is the warnings file (itself filtered from the build log), and a blacklist file excluded_filenames.txt with file names, one per line.

I know how it's done in procedural languages like Perl or AWK, and I've even done it with combinations of Linux commands such as cut, comm, and sort.

But I feel that I should be really close with xargs, and just can't see the last step.

I know that if excluded_filenames.txt has only 1 file name in it, then

```
grep -v foo.txt `cat excluded_filenames.txt`
```

will do it.

And I know that I can get the filenames one per line with

```
xargs -L1 -a excluded_filenames.txt
```

So how do I combine those two into a single solution, without explicit loops in a procedural language?

Looking for the simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the `-f` option (or you can use `fgrep` which is the same):

```
grep -vf excluded_filenames.txt foo.txt
```

You could also use `-F` which is more directly the answer to what you asked:

```
grep -vF "`cat excluded_filenames.txt`" foo.txt
```

from `man grep`

```
-f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.

-F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
```

Comment: Thanks! grep is even more powerful, all by itself, than I realized. And I guess I should have looked at its man page first ...

Comment: I think your answer is slightly incorrect, the `cat` in the second example shouldn't be there, line should be `grep -vF excluded_filenames.txt foo.txt`, it would also be wise to use `-f` at the same time to avoid `.` matching any character.

Comment: @Hasturkun, i don't think so, `excluded_filenames.txt` is not the text to search for, it is a file which contains a list of patterns.

Comment: Urgh, I misread, thought `-F` was obtain from file. in any case, combining the two is a good idea, no need for `cat`

Comment: So as far as I can tell, from http://ss64.com/bash/fgrep.html, I should use the -f to take the patterns from file and the -F to speed up execution when the pattern file is long. That would make grep -vfF excluded_filenames.txt foo.txt or fgrep -vf excluded_filenames.txt foo.txt with no need for cat